# Cheap proof that $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ contains a rank $2$ free subgroup

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

It's a well-known fact, used in the proof of the Banach-Tarski paradox for example, that $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to the free group $\mathbb{F}_2$ on two generators.  Is there a cheap way to prove this fact along the following lines?

Any non-trivial reduced word $w$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ defines a map
$$f_w : \mathrm{SO}(3) \times \mathrm{SO}(3) \rightarrow \mathrm{SO}(3)$$
by sending a pair $(a, b)$ to the value of $w$ when the two generators of the free group are sent to $a$ and $b$.  We want to show that the union of the $f_w^{-1}(I)$ over all $w$ is not the whole of the domain.  One could try to do this by showing that:

1. For each $w$ the set $f_w^{-1}(I)$ is "small" in $\mathrm{SO}(3) \times \mathrm{SO}(3)$ (e.g. measure zero, meagre, real algebraic).
2. The union of countable many "small" sets is "small".

Is there a way to make this scheme work?

It seems intuitive that any non-abelian Lie group should contain a copy of $\mathbb{F}_2$, just for size reasons.  Is this the case, and can a similar argument be used in this general setting?

Comment: Yes, this argument does work but you have to know ahead of time that, say, $SL(2,{\mathbb R})$ contains a nonabelian free subgroup. If you are OK with this, then indeed there is a "cheap" proof.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Could you expand on this please?

Comment: I could but first you have to tell me about SL(2,R), otherwise it will be pointless.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  I'm happy to assume whatever you need about $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start with a few observations. First of all, it suffices to prove that the group $K=SU(2)$ contains a free nonabelian subgroup since $SO(3)$ is isomorphic to the quotient $SU(2)/\{\pm I\}$. Now, the group $G= SL(2, {\mathbb C})$ is a connected 3-dimensional complex manifold; it contains $SU(2)$ as a subgroup. Moreover, if $\phi: SL(2, {\mathbb C})\to {\mathbb C}$ is a holomorphic function which is constant on an open nonempty subset of $SU(2)$ then it is constant on the entire $SL(2, {\mathbb C})$. (This is proven by observing that in some local holomorphic coordinates, $SU(2)\subset SL(2, {\mathbb C})$ appears as ${\mathbb R}^3\subset {\mathbb C}^3$.)

The same holds for functions on $G\times G$: If a holomorphic function on $G\times G$ is constant on an open nonempty subset of $K\times K$ then it is constant on $G\times G$.

Now, consider the set of homomorphisms $Hom(F_2, SU(2))$. It is naturally identified with the product $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ (by recording the images of the generators under each homomorphism $\rho$); the same for the set of homomorphisms $Hom(F_2, SL(2, {\mathbb C}))$. Each element $w\in F_2$ defines a holomorphic function $f_w: G\times G\to G$ by the formula:
$$
f_w(\rho):= \rho(w)\in SL(2, {\mathbb C}).  
$$
(The fact that for the two generators $a, b$ of $F_2$ the functions 
$f_a, f_b$ are holomorphic is immediate; the general case follows, by matrix multiplication, from the fact that the products and sums of holomorphic functions are holomorphic.) 
For each $w\in F_2$ define two closed subsets: $J_w:= f_w^{-1}(I)\subset G\times G$ and $I_w:=J_w\cap K\times K\subset K\times K$.

By the observations made in the 1st paragraph we have the following dichotomy:

For every $w\in F_2$ either:

1. $I_w$ is nowhere dense in $K\times K$, or
2. $J_w= G \times G$.

Now, if we knew that for every $w\ne 1$, $J_w$ is a proper subset of $G\times G$, it would follow from the Baire category theorem (since $K\times K$ is metrizable and $F_2$ is countable) that 
$$
Hom(F_2, K)\ne \bigcup_{w\in F_2 -1} I_w .
$$ 
In other words, we would know that there exists a homomorphism 
$$
\rho: F_2\to SU(2)
$$
with trivial kernel, as required.

The issue then becomes: How do we know that for every $w\in F_2 - 1$ there exists a homomorphism $\rho: F_2\to SL(2, {\mathbb C})$ such that $\rho(w)\ne I$? This would immediately follow if we knew that there exists a monomorphism $\rho: F_2\to SL(2, {\mathbb R})$.

How to prove existence of such monomorphism is a separate story. Among ways to prove this is to look closely at the modular group $SL(2, {\mathbb Z})$, or to construct a complete hyperbolic structure on a surface with free fundamental group, or to "play ping-pong'', etc.

Comment: This is nice.  It would be great if one could give a soft argument for $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ that didn't rely on some cleverness such as the methods you suggest in the final paragraph.  But perhaps I'm hoping for too much, in that such a proof (which didn't use much specific about $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$) might have to apply in situations where the result is not true.

Comment: I'm vaguely aware of the Tits alternative but my group theory is not good enough to be able to see an easy example of a Lie group which doesn't contain an $F_2$, except for the obvious case where the group is abelian.  Do you know such an example?

Comment: @Jez: A connected Lie group $G$ contains a free nonabelian subgroup iff $G$ is not solvable. The standard example of a solvable connected Lie group which is not abelian is the group of upper triangular complex matrices. As for my proof, I think you will not get anything simpler than that apart from following Hausdorff's arguments which are more clever than mine and use the action of the Galois group. His proof does not use anything like Baire category.