# Subgroup of PSL(2,R) generated by two elements with elliptic commutator is not free.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Suppose $[A,B]$ is elliptic for some $A,B \in PSL(2;\mathbb{R})$. Then $\langle A,B \rangle < PSL(2;\mathbb{R})$ is not free. Is there any nice way to see this? If $[A,B]$ is elliptic of finite order then it is clear, but what about elliptic of infinite order?

The claim is from: http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/keenl/LiftingFreeSubgroups.pdf (the bottom paragraph of page 12).

Comment: They probably assume discreteness, since the claim is false otherwise.

Comment: The claim (in the paper) says "...the commutator is elliptic and the group is not free, but it may be discrete". This phrasing led me to believe that freeness is independent of discreteness.

Comment: It might be just a poor choice of words. In any case, my comment stands.

Comment: Does the answer change if we replace "$\langle A,B \rangle$ is not free" with "$\langle A,B \rangle$ is not freely generated by $A$ and $B$"?

Comment: No, it is the same.

Comment: A proof is similar to my argument in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016495/cheap-proof-that-mathrmso3-contains-a-rank-2-free-subgroup/2019900#2019900

Comment: I checked the paper: I think the claim is just the result of sloppy editing since from the beginning of the section the authors seem to assume discreteness. I would ignore the claim: It is obvious for discrete subgroups and false in general.